# How to reference a stack from another stack in AWS CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I currently have my resources in the **us-east-2** region as **Stack A** and AWS CDK is creating some resources by default in another region, let's call it **Stack B**, as part of a cross-region replication since in my Stack A I am specifying **us-east-1** as the region where the replication is going to be. However, I need to reference Stack B, which is being created in us-east-1, from Stack A. If I use `this`, it only takes me Stack A name.

In summary:

- Stack A: My resources in us-east-2
- Stack B: Stack created by default by CDK for cross-region replication in us-east-1

For example:

```
    NagSuppressions.addResourceSuppressionsByPath(this, `/${this.stackName}/SharedInfra/...`, [
      {
        id: "AwsSolutions-S1",
        reason:
          "lorem ipsum",
      },
    ]);
```

`this` and `${this.stackName}` take the name of the current stack which is Stack A and I need to reference Stack B.

How can I reference Stack B from Stack A?

Comment: Can you share the part of your CDK code where you establish the replication from us-east-2 to us-east-1?

Comment: @DougNaphas This is done by default by the CDK pipeline using a support stack called CrossRegionSupportStacks https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.CodePipeline.html#reusecrossregionsupportstacks. That's why I don't know how to take that support Stack B and reference it.